# Http 500 error when creating workspace using GeoServer REST-API

Tags: geoserver, geoserver-rest-api

Trying to create a new wokspace at GeoServer 2.12 via REST-API I'm getting `Http 500` error. I tried [this advise](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/257267/5666) but it didn't work.

Request:

```
:~> curl -v -u admin:geoserver -X POST -H  "accept: 
application/json" -H  "content-type: application/json" -d "{  
\"name\": \"string\"}" 
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces?default=false
```

**UPD:** Similar request but with `xml` and not `json` works as supposed to.

Response:

```
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying ::1...
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 8080 (#0)
* Server auth using Basic with user 'admin'
> POST /geoserver/rest/workspaces?default=false HTTP/1.1
> Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46Z2Vvc2VydmVy
> User-Agent: curl/7.37.0
> Host: localhost:8080
> accept: application/json
> content-type: application/json
> Content-Length: 20
> 
* upload completely sent off: 20 out of 20 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 500 Server Error
< X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
* Server Jetty(9.2.13.v20150730) is not blacklisted
< Server: Jetty(9.2.13.v20150730)
< 
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

Geoserver log

```
01 Apr 03:53:44 ERROR [geoserver.rest] - name
com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException: name
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.DefaultMapper.realClass(DefaultMapper.java:81)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:125)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.DynamicProxyMapper.realClass(DynamicProxyMapper.java:55)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:125)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.PackageAliasingMapper.realClass(PackageAliasingMapper.java:88)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:125)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.ClassAliasingMapper.realClass(ClassAliasingMapper.java:79)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:125)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.ArrayMapper.realClass(ArrayMapper.java:74)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:125)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.SecurityMapper.realClass(SecurityMapper.java:71)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:125)
        at org.geoserver.config.util.SecureXStream$DetailedSecurityExceptionWrapper.realClass(SecureXStream.java:150)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:125)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CachingMapper.realClass(CachingMapper.java:47)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.util.HierarchicalStreams.readClassType(HierarchicalStreams.java:29)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.start(TreeUnmarshaller.java:133)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.unmarshal(AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.java:32)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.unmarshal(XStream.java:1486)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.unmarshal(XStream.java:1466)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.fromXML(XStream.java:1346)
        at org.geoserver.config.util.XStreamPersister.load(XStreamPersister.java:626)
        at org.geoserver.rest.converters.XStreamJSONMessageConverter.readInternal(XStreamJSONMessageConverter.java:63)
        at org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractHttpMessageConverter.read(AbstractHttpMessageConverter.java:193)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.readWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.java:217)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.readWithMessageConverters(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:150)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:128)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:121)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:158)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:128)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:116)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:808)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1669)
        at org.geoserver.filters.ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.doFilter(ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.java:28)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
        at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:75)
        at org.geoserver.wms.animate.AnimatorFilter.doFilter(AnimatorFilter.java:71)
        at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:71)
        at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:46)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
        at org.geoserver.platform.AdvancedDispatchFilter.doFilter(AdvancedDispatchFilter.java:50)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:316)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:69)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:73)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:69)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:73)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:54)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:69)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:213)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:73)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerBasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerBasicAuthenticationFilter.java:84)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:69)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:91)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter$1.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:53)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:73)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176)
        at org.geoserver.security.GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.java:152)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
        at org.geoserver.filters.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:88)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
        at org.geoserver.filters.XFrameOptionsFilter.doFilter(XFrameOptionsFilter.java:89)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
        at org.geoserver.filters.GZIPFilter.doFilter(GZIPFilter.java:48)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
        at org.geoserver.filters.SessionDebugFilter.doFilter(SessionDebugFilter.java:48)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
        at org.geoserver.filters.FlushSafeFilter.doFilter(FlushSafeFilter.java:44)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:585)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:577)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:215)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:110)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:499)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:310)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<s>Seems that despite documentation says otherwise GeoServer **do not support** json-based requests. Only XML works.</s>

It turns out that json **is** supported, but the documentation itself is wrong. You need to reconstruct json-schema from the xml example.

Comment: it worked with xml, but why did they put a lot of json examples in theirs offical page? it is interesting

Comment: @ÖmürBilgili, I updated the answer - JOSN is supported, but the schema needs to be reconstructed from xml-examples.

Comment: Thank You so much for posting this.  I have been trying to figure out what was wrong with my JSON request for hours.

Comment: Thanks! I've just wasted an hour trying to figure this out. Someone should correct the documentation

Answer (score 1):

GeoServer if it supports the creation of workspaces by API REST by JSON

CURL JSON = curl curl -v -u admin:geoserver -XPOST -H "Content-type: application/json" -d "{"workspace":{"name":"holaaaaaa"}}" http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces

[image]